# How to disable particular logs while running serenity scan

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j, serenity-bdd

We are running serenity scan on our spring boot application with logging enabled. Below are few debug logs before adding logback.xml file to our project.

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /url HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: text/plain
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application.json
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: "Basic absgdjdhhdasaaxaqrgjn=="
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HTTPClient/4.5.13

DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /url HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: text/plain
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application.json
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: "Basic c2hddjd7xnamnxjaa2kHfdqqq=="
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HTTPClient/4.5.13
```

We want to remove only above set of lines from the logs. So We added below logback.xml file under src/test/resources but when we run serenity scan it is not showing the logs (either story details OR test started/test failed banner etc), only it is showing all stories passed and build success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
   <logger name="org.apache.http.headers"/>
   <logger name="org.apache.http.wire"/>
</configuration>
```

Someone please suggest how to eliminate only headers and wire debug logs and keep rest of the logs.

Comment: Any suggestions on this??

Comment: you can set specify class level to disable some DEBUG log. first ensure the logger name is right ,because the first letter of class name is always uppercase. <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="INFO"/>